# When I add the class "img-responsive" to an image tag, my images become large and no longer fit into my div

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

My images were contained to my DIV. When I add the class "img-responsive" to an image tag, my images become large and no longer fit into my div. I am using Bootstrap 3.3.0

```
<img class="img-responsive" id="groupaImage" src="Images/set1-hip-2car.jpg" class="imageright" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1;"/>

.imageright {   
height:auto;
width:auto;
float: left;
padding-right: 5px;
border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
border: 5px solid #9c9c9c;
}
```

Comment: it's class="img-responsive imageright". What you have is incorrect html with two class=.

Comment: Also, inline styles are not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what are yout doing here

You have two class?

Use like this

```
<img class="img-responsive imageright position-absolute" id="groupaImage" src="Images/set1-hip-2car.jpg"/>

.imageright {   
 height:auto;
 width:auto;
 float: left;
 padding-right: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
 border: 5px solid #9c9c9c;
}   

.position-absolute{
 position: absolute; 
 z-index: 1;
}
```

But i think this will not work also, because you have absolute element and float left??